# Basic Encryption algorithm in Java not decrypting

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to implement TEA (tiny encryption algorithm) in Java, to encode a `byte[]` containing audio, of size 512.

Here's my encrypt function:

```
//Encrypt 64bit/8byte buffer with 128bit/16byte key
public byte[] encrypt(int[] data, int[] key) { 
    int x = data[0]; 
    int y = data[1]; 
    ByteBuffer encrypted = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
    int sum = 0; 
    int constant = 0x9e3779b9; //magic constant

    for (int k = 0; k < 32; ++k) { 
        sum += constant; 
        x += (y << 4 & 0xfffffff0) + key[0] ^ y + sum ^ (y >> 5 & 0x7ffffff) + key[1]; 
        y += (x << 4 & 0xfffffff0) + key[2] ^ x + sum ^ (x >> 5 & 0x7ffffff) + key[3]; 
    }
    encrypted.putInt(x);
    encrypted.putInt(y);
    return encrypted.array();
}
```

and decrypt:

```
public byte[] decrypt(int[] data, int[] key) { 
    int x = data[0]; 
    int y = data[1]; 
    ByteBuffer decrypted = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
    int sum = 0xC6EF3720; //32*delta
    int constant = 0x9e3779b9; //magic constant

    for (int k = 0; k < 32; ++k) { 
        x -= (x << 4 & 0xfffffff0) + key[2] ^ x + sum ^ (x >> 5 & 0x7ffffff) + key[3]; 
        y -= (y << 4 & 0xfffffff0) + key[0] ^ y + sum ^ (y >> 5 & 0x7ffffff) + key[1]; 
        sum -= constant; 
    }
    decrypted.putInt(x); 
    decrypted.putInt(y);
    return decrypted.array();
}
```

and my encrypt call:

```
ByteBuffer unwrapEncrypt = ByteBuffer.allocate(512);
int[] encryptionKey = {55555, 8888, 123857, 912029};

//block is a byte[] with length 512
ByteBuffer plainText = ByteBuffer.wrap(block);
for (int j = 0; j < block.length / 8; j++) {
    //Initiate array for int pairs
    int[] plainTextInts = new int[2];
    plainTextInts[0] = plainText.getInt();
    plainTextInts[1] = plainText.getInt();
    //Encrypt and store
    unwrapEncrypt.put(encrypt(plainTextInts, encryptionKey));
}
```

and decrypt call:

```
ByteBuffer audioToPlay = ByteBuffer.allocate(512);
int[] decryptionKey = {55555, 8888, 123857, 912029};

//audio is a byte[] with length 512
ByteBuffer cipherText = ByteBuffer.wrap(audio);
for (int j = 0; j < audio.length / 8; j++) {
    int[] plainTextInts = new int[2];
    //Initiate array for int pairs
    plainTextInts[0] = cipherText.getInt();
    plainTextInts[1] = cipherText.getInt();
    //Decrypt and store
    audioToPlay.put(decrypt(plainTextInts, decryptionKey));
}
```

Sorry for the mass of code - I've tried analysis on sent audio and received decrypted data - they're both of correct length, just entirely different. If I remove these 4 blocks of code, the audio is perfect. Can anyone spot what's up? Thanks

Comment: `>>` -> `>>>` ?

Comment: Where abouts do you mean?

Comment: In the shift right. Oh, and I think `&` takes precedence.

Comment: So `(x >> 5 & 0x7ffffff)` and `(y >> 5 & 0x7ffffff)` --> `(x >>> 5 & 0x7ffffff)` and `(y >> 5 & 0x7ffffff)` inside `encrypt` and `decrypt`?

Comment: `(x >>> 5) & 0x7fffffff` I think. Note that I didn't even look at the description of TEA yet, but this seems incorrect to me. Actually, even the above seems incorrect, because you would not need the `&` for this code. Test step by step. Should it be rotate instead of shift? Hmmm, I'll take a look. If I can keep my eyes open that is.

Comment: No you need shift, but you need shift without sign extension, so `>>>`. Then you don't need the & masking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems there is a bug in your `decrpyt()` method when comparing it to [Wikipedia' s description of TEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm). You have to exchange x and y on the left of the `-=` operators. The following seems to work for me:

```
public byte[] decrypt(int[] data, int[] key) { 
    int x = data[0]; 
    int y = data[1]; 
    ByteBuffer decrypted = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
    int sum = 0xC6EF3720; //32*delta
    int constant = 0x9e3779b9; //magic constant

    for (int k = 0; k < 32; ++k) { 
        y -= (x << 4 & 0xfffffff0) + key[2] ^ x + sum ^ (x >> 5 & 0x7ffffff) + key[3]; 
        x -= (y << 4 & 0xfffffff0) + key[0] ^ y + sum ^ (y >> 5 & 0x7ffffff) + key[1]; 
        sum -= constant; 
    }
    decrypted.putInt(x); 
    decrypted.putInt(y);
    return decrypted.array();
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's another error I guess. Note that getting decryption working doesn't mean that it is a correct implementation of TEA. You need to test against test vectors or a known good implementation for that.

Comment: And, note that even two people can have the same mistake during an implementation. If you have test vectors then it is easy to see, and if it is the first time implementation by designers it is not easy to see.